# What are the physical reasons for considering the Maxwell invariant ${\cal G}=E.B$ in the action?

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, invariants

As I know, the Maxwell invariant ${\cal G}=E.B$ is the fundamental invariant such as ${\cal F}=\frac{1}{2}\left( {{{\bf{B}}^2} - {{\bf{E}}^2}} \right)$ that can be used to construct all possible invariants in electrodynamics. I was wondering what are the physical reasons to consider this invariant (in the form of ${\cal G}^2$) in the electrodynamics Lagrangian. Why the presence of ${\cal G}$ in essential in the Lagrangian? Which physical phenomena can not be explained in the absence of ${\cal G}$? Is it necessary to have ${\cal G}$ in order to construct Lagrangian in higher dimensions?

Comment: Why do you put *anything* into a Lagrangian? Why are you happy with $F^2$ terms?

Answer (score 4):

$\int \theta(x) {\bf E} \cdot {\bf B}d^4x $ occurs in the action for [axion electrodynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axion). Where have you seen it to higher powers? Perhaps in the quantum corrections due to fermion loops?

In higher dimensions there are more invariants than just $|E|^2-|B|^2$ and ${\bf E} \cdot {\bf B}$.

Comment: In the classical nonlinear electrodynamics, e.g., Born-Infeld Lagrangian.

Comment: Born-Infeld is not actually *necessary* in the action, but such terms do arise as correction when you integrate out the fermions, as was done by Schwinger for example.

Comment: In fact, in all nonlinear electrodynamics models it appears. I know the presence of ${\cal G}$ is essential to describe vacuum polarization effects classically via these nonlinear electrodynamics. The vacuum polarization effects in QED are due to one-loop corrections. I am searching for other physical consequences of presence of ${\cal G}$.

Comment: Could you please introduce a reference for what you have said: "such terms do arise as correction when you integrate out the fermions, as was done by Schwinger for example". I am eager to find out more.

Comment: I would be grateful if you let me know how you found that the higher powers are related to quantum corrections due to fermion loops.

Comment: @Kheeyal https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Heisenberg_Lagrangian

Comment: @ Andrew thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

The modern way of looking for things ([effective field theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_field_theory)) is that you should include *every* term in the action consistent with the symmetries and containing the degrees of freedom you are working with. So from that point of view, you would need a reason *not* to include $\mathcal{G}$.

As you mentioned, in four dimensions the Lorentz invariant scalar combinations of $E$ and $B$ are $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{G}$. However, since $\mathcal{G}$ is a *total derivative*, it does not contribute to the equations of motion. So it's a bit like adding zero to the action; it has no effect. (In Yang-Mills theory the analogous total derivative terms *can* lead to subtle quantum mechanical effects like [CP violation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_CP_problem), but those effects don't occur in electromagnetism).

If you add an additional scalar degree of freedom (an axion) you can make this term more interesting, as discussed by mike stone in their answer.

Comment: Thank you very much. A great answer. Can we say that this total derivative leads to the vacuum polarization which is  a quantum mechanical effect?

Comment: No, it has no effect at all.

Comment: Vacuum polarization is a 1-loop effect that comes from the $\mathcal{F}$ term.

Comment: thank you. Could you please give me a reference? I thought it comes from the ${\cal G}$ term.

Comment: @Kheeyal I should say it comes from the $\mathcal{F}$ term plus an interaction with a charged field. But the $\mathcal{G}$ term is not involved. Take a look at the definition of vacuum polarization (particularly the diagram) on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuum_polarization). A detailed calculation of this diagram is given (among many other places) in [Srednicki's notes on QED](https://cns.gatech.edu/~predrag/courses/PHYS-7147-05/Srednicki-IIIa.pdf) in Chapter 62 (see Fig 6). The Lagrangian is given in Eq 189-192, no $\mathcal{G}$ term (which is $F\tilde{F}$ in that notation).

Comment: Thank you very much.